# Windows add empty line to start of txt batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, echo

I would like to add an empty line to the beginning of multiple text files.
To append this to the end would work probably work just the following in Windows cmd.

```
echo. >> *.txt
```

How do I add the line to the beginning of the file instead of the end? It is also important to preserve encoding and everything else within the files. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %f in (*.txt) do (echo.&type "%f")>tmp.file && move /y tmp.file "%f"
```

It can probably be done better than this, as I am using a `tmp.file` temporary file (check not to have one with that name already)

Comment: Looks better than mine but not going to bless it before I test it!

Comment: Confirmed as working.

Comment: Looks good, did exactly what was required and did not mess with the encoding. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Edited answer after feedback:

$ (echo. && echo File.txt) > ./temp.txt&rename temp.txt File.txt

Comment: Can't test it on this machine so only 80% sure...

Comment: I doubt this is going to work David...

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP is using Windows. Your answer looks like a bash script.

Comment: I have read it carefully thank you - I think you need to double check things yourself? It is designed for execution in a .bat (batch) file on Windows, not a .sh (bash) script on *NIX

Comment: F:\test>(echo. && echo File.txt) > ./temp.txt; rename temp.txt File.txt
rename was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Ok, so I've snuck a ';' instead of '&' in there.. I did say I couldn't test on this box (locked down Win7). Try F:\test>(echo. && echo File.txt) > ./temp.txt&rename temp.txt

Comment: @DavidPostill is right David... `echo File.txt` literally echoes the "File.txt" string. You may have thought of `type`

Comment: That won't work either. `F:\test>type temp.txt` produces "File.txt"

Comment: You still have a dollar sign, so you haven't thought this through at all, or tested it. I suggest you test before posting.

Comment: `rename temp.txt File.txt` - "A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found."

Comment: Asking me to test before posting is fair enough but asking someone to give up? Not constructive!

Comment: @DavidVernon  It's not fair to just keep amending things and expecting other people to test them for you. Test it yourself.

Comment: @DavidVernon In any case, your solution (when it finally works) would only work for a single file. OP siad "I would like to add an empty line to the beginning of multiple text files.". You don't even attempt to address this part of the question.

Comment: Concur, see my existing comment to Salvo's answer! :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30866/discussion-on-answer-by-david-vernon-windows-add-empty-line-to-start-of-txt-batc).